# How to extract xml attribute using Python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

For:

```
<foo>
 <bar key="value">text</bar>
</foo>
```

How do I get "value"?

```
xml.findtext("./bar[@key]")
```

Throws an error.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This will find the first instance of an element named `bar` and return the value of the attribute `key`.

```
In [52]: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

In [53]: xml=ET.fromstring(contents)

In [54]: xml.find('./bar').attrib['key']
Out[54]: 'value'
```

Comment: @Stevoisiak, i have similar problem                                                                     `<image height="940" id="0" name="C02032-390.jpg" width="1820">                      
    <box label="Objects" occluded="1" xbr="255" xtl="0" ybr="624" ytl="509">
        <attribute name="Class">Car</attribute>
    </box>                                                                                                                  
 </image>` I would like to access "Car" from the attribute.

Answer (score 12):

**Getting child tag's attribute value in a XML using ElementTree**

Parse the XML file and get the `root` tag and then using `[0]` will give us first child tag. Similarly `[1], [2]` gives us subsequent child tags. After getting child tag use `.attrib[attribute_name]` to get value of that attribute.

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> xmlstr = '<foo><bar key="value">text</bar></foo>'
>>> root = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
>>> root.tag
'foo'
>>> root[0].tag
'bar'
>>> root[0].attrib['key']
'value'
```

If the xml content is in file. You should do below task to get the `root`.

```
>>> tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
>>> root = tree.getroot()
```

Comment: I get error saying AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'fromstring'

Answer (score 2):

By following method you can get all attributes from xml (in Dictionary)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
xmlString= "<feed xml:lang='en'><title>World Wide Web</title><subtitle lang='en'>Programming challenges</subtitle><link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://google.com/'/><updated>2019-12-25T12:00:00</updated></feed>"
xml= etree.fromstring(xmlString)  

def get_attr(xml):
    attributes = []
    for child in (xml):
        if len(child.attrib)!= 0:
            attributes.append(child.attrib)
        get_attr(child)
    return attributes
attributes = get_attr(xml)

print(attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expression:

> ./bar[@key]

It means: *`bar` children having `key` attribute*

If you want to select the attribute, use this relative expression:

```
bar/@key
```

It means: *the `key` attribute of `bar` children*

Of course, you need to consider to use a fully compliant XPath engine like [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

Comment: Not sure if it's ElementTree or Google App Engine but the use of '@'  raises SyntaxError("unsupported path syntax (%s)" % op)
SyntaxError: unsupported path syntax (@)

Comment: @Will Merydith: Please, read my last sentence. Basic `ElementTree` API it's not a full complain XPath engine...

Comment: OK.  I'll see if I can find a module that will work on GAE/Py2.5.5.

Comment: It seems that python ElementTree does not support syntax like `bar/@key` and you have to use `xxx.attribut.get("key")` for the appropriate `xxx`.

Answer (score 0):

dipenparmar12 function will not return the childrens child attributes. Because the function is recursive the attributes list will be set to a empty list for each call. This function will has return the childrens child.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
xml= etree.fromstring(xmlString) 


 def get_attr(xml, attributes):
     for child in (xml):
         if len(child.attrib)!= 0:
             attributes.append(child.attrib)
         get_attr(child,attributes)
     return attributes

  attributes = get_attr(xml,[])
  print(attributes)
```

Answer (score -1):

For going deeper into the tree this type of functions can be used.

```
root[1][2][0].tag  # For displaying the nodes
root[1][2][0].text # For showing what's inside the node
```