# Get all xml attribute values in python3 using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I have the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank updated="yes">69</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

I want to write python 3 code using ElementTree to get all country names. So the end result should be a `dict` or `array` of

> ['Liechtenstein','Singapore','Panama']

I am trying to do this using Xpath but getting nowhere. So my code is as follows

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = tree.getroot()

names = root.findall("./country/@name")
```

However the above does not work as I feel my xpath is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) to get all of the `country` tags and get the `name` attribute from the [`.attrib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib) dictionary:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """your xml here"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data) 
print([el.attrib.get('name') for el in tree.findall('.//country')])
```

Prints `['Liechtenstein', 'Singapore', 'Panama']`.

Note that you cannot get the attribute values using an xpath expression `//country/@name` since `xml.etree.ElementTree` provides only [limited Xpath support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax).

---

FYI, [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) provides a more complete xpath support and therefore makes it easier to get the attribute values:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

data = """your xml here"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
print(tree.xpath('//country/@name'))
```

Prints `['Liechtenstein', 'Singapore', 'Panama']`.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to all names into an array in a single line.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: @VinayJoseph I've also added an `lxml` option - just in case you are okay with using third-party modules. And also added links to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

 xml=ET.fromstring(contents)



xml.find('./element').attrib['key']
```

Chek the source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573237/how-to-extract-xml-attribute-using-python-elementtree)