# get attribute from xml-node with specific value

Tags: python, xml

I have an XSD-file where I need to get a namespace as defined in the root-tag:

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:abw="http://www.liegenschaftsbestandsmodell.de/ns/abw/1.0.1.0" xmlns:adv="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0" xmlns:bfm="http://www.liegenschaftsbestandsmodell.de/ns/bfm/1.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:sc="http://www.interactive-instruments.de/ShapeChange/AppInfo" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.liegenschaftsbestandsmodell.de/ns/abw/1.0.1.0" version="1.0.1.0">
  <!-- elements -->
</schema>
```

Now as the `targetNamespace` of this schema-definition is `"http://www.liegenschaftsbestandsmodell.de/ns/abw/1.0.1.0"` I need to get the short identifier for this namespace - which is `abw`. To get this identifier I have to get that attribute from the root-tag that has the exact same value as my `targetNamespace` (I can´t rely on the identifier beeing part of the `targetNamespace`-string allready, this may change in the future).

On this question [How to extract xml attribute using Python ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573237/how-to-extract-xml-attribute-using-python-elementtree) I found how to get the value of an attribute given by its name. However I don´t know the attributes name, only its value, so what can I do when I have a value and want to select the attribute having this value?

I think of something like this:

```
for key in root.attrib.keys():
    if(root.attrib[key] == targetNamespace):
        return root.attrib[key]
```

but `root.attrib` only contains `elementFormDefault`, `targetNamespace` and `version`, but not `xmlns:abw`.

Comment: do you want to search  name spaces

Answer (score 1):

string must be Unicode else error will appear

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#62>", line 1, in <module>
    it = etree.iterparse(StringIO(xml))
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str
```

code:

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> xml=u"""<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:abw="http://www.liegenschaftsbestandsmodell.de/ns/abw/1.0.1.0" xmlns:adv="http://www.adv-online.de/namespaces/adv/gid/6.0" xmlns:bfm="http://www.liegenschaftsbestandsmodell.de/ns/bfm/1.0" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:sc="http://www.interactive-instruments.de/ShapeChange/AppInfo" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.liegenschaftsbestandsmodell.de/ns/abw/1.0.1.0" version="1.0.1.0">
  <!-- elements -->
</schema>"""
>>> ns = dict([
    node for _, node in ElementTree.iterparse(
        StringIO(xml), events=['start-ns']
    )
])
>>> for k,v in ns.iteritems():
    if v=='http://www.liegenschaftsbestandsmodell.de/ns/abw/1.0.1.0':
        print k
```

output:

```
abw
```

Comment: This seems to work, however I don´t understand the dictionaries definition using the for-loop `node for _, node in ..`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere look at name space section [link](http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm)

Comment: @HimBromBeere `iterparse` return the `event `and `element` i ignored event .  element  as `tupel ` containing `namespace `and `value` the i converted the result into `dict ` for easy search

Answer (score 0):

Using minidom instead of ETree did it:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as DOM
tree = DOM.parse(myFile)
root = tree.documentElement
targetNamespace = root.getAttribute("targetNamespace")

d = dict(root.attributes.items())
for key in d:
    if d[key] == targetNamespace: return key
```

This will return either `targetNamespace` or `xmlns:abw` depending on what comes first in the xsd. Of course we should ignore the first case, but this goes out of scope of this question.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#154>", line 1, in <module>
    targetNamespace = root.getattribute("targetNamespace")
AttributeError: Element instance has no attribute 'getattribute'`

Comment: `getAttribute` instead of `getattribute`

Comment: @HishamKaram Thank you for the hint, updated accordingly.