# Retrieve attribute from XML node using namespace in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, wsdl

I know that there are a few examples already of retrieving specific attributes from XML nodes, but I've not been successful in doing so with a namespace. I am able to retrieve an attribute without any namespaces, such as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4573304/3480297).

Suppose I have the following "example.wsdl" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="Name of the file">
  <wsdl:documentation>Documentation of the file</wsdl:documentation>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I'd like to retrieve the "name" attribute of the node "wsdl:defintions"
I have tried doing the below:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("example.wsdl")
rootWSDL = tree.getroot()

print(tree.find('./wsdl:definitions', rootWSDL.nsmap).attrib['name'])
```

However, the above returns an empty list with the following message:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrib'

For what it's worth, the Python version I am using is 3.7.5

Answer (score 3):

You can directly access it from the root.

**Ex:**

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("example.wsdl")
rootWSDL = tree.getroot()
print(rootWSDL.attrib['name'])

#-->Name of the file
```

Comment: Thank you. But suppose I have a use case where the node in question is not directly below the root? I'd like to find a way where I can explicitly specify which node I want to target rather than where it lies in the structure.

Comment: Use `print(tree.find('wsdl:definitions', rootWSDL.nsmap).attrib['name'])` without `./`

Comment: Adam: *But suppose I have a use case where the node in question is not directly below the root?* Why did you not ask about that use case in the first place then? @Rakesh did provide a reasonable answer. You have started a bounty, but the XML in the question has not been changed. What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

In your example you can't find the wsdl:definitions node with find because the rootWSDL is that node. If this is always the case just take rootWSDL.attrib['name'].

Your current xpath will only find elements that are direct children of rootWSDL. If your intent is to find some other namespaced node anywhere in the document simply make it a global xpath, i.e. replace:

```
'./wsdl:targetElementName'
```

with

```
'//wsdl:targetElementName'
```